# Не срабатывает border-bottom

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, scss

в шапке есть разделение, пытаюсь сделать его через свойство border-bottom у блока header__top, но он не срабатывает, почему?

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__bg">
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__top">
        <div class="header__column">
          <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="/images/logo-black.svg" alt="Логотип" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header__column right">
          <div class="header__clock">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#FF1A3B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M13.5631 11.7661L10.7746 9.67464V5.41441C10.7746 4.98605 10.4283 4.6398 9.99997 4.6398C9.57161 4.6398 9.22536 4.98605 9.22536 5.41441V10.062C9.22536 10.306 9.34001 10.5361 9.5352 10.6817L12.6336 13.0055C12.773 13.11 12.9357 13.1604 13.0976 13.1604C13.3338 13.1604 13.5662 13.0543 13.718 12.8498C13.9752 12.5081 13.9055 12.0225 13.5631 11.7661Z"
              />
              <path
                d="M10 0C4.48566 0 0 4.48566 0 10C0 15.5143 4.48566 20 10 20C15.5143 20 20 15.5143 20 10C20 4.48566 15.5143 0 10 0ZM10 18.4508C5.34082 18.4508 1.54918 14.6592 1.54918 10C1.54918 5.34082 5.34082 1.54918 10 1.54918C14.66 1.54918 18.4508 5.34082 18.4508 10C18.4508 14.6592 14.6592 18.4508 10 18.4508Z"
              />
            </svg>
            8:00 - 20:00<span class="red"> без выходных</span>
          </div>
          <div class="header__geo">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#FF1A3B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M15.9334 2.45962C12.6541 -0.819657 7.34625 -0.82001 4.06662 2.45962C0.787416 5.73878 0.786906 11.0467 4.06662 14.3264L9.55655 19.8163C9.8015 20.0613 10.1986 20.0612 10.4435 19.8163L15.9334 14.3264C19.2126 11.0472 19.2131 5.73929 15.9334 2.45962ZM15.0464 13.4395L10 18.4859L4.95357 13.4395C2.17097 10.6569 2.17097 6.1292 4.95357 3.34661C7.7362 0.564054 12.2637 0.563976 15.0464 3.34661C17.829 6.12916 17.829 10.6568 15.0464 13.4395Z"
              />
              <path
                d="M10 4.64191C7.92688 4.64191 6.2489 6.31953 6.2489 8.39297C6.2489 10.4661 7.9266 12.144 10 12.144C12.0732 12.144 13.7511 10.4663 13.7511 8.39297C13.7511 6.31988 12.0735 4.64191 10 4.64191ZM11.7655 10.1584C11.7415 10.1584 11.1503 10.8897 10 10.8897C8.6201 10.8897 7.50326 9.77304 7.50326 8.39297C7.50326 7.01311 8.61995 5.89626 10 5.89626C12.2416 5.89626 13.319 8.60496 11.7655 10.1584Z"
              />
            </svg>
            ш. Энтузиастов д. 31, стр. 40
          </div>
          <div class="header__phone">
            <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#FF1A3B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M4.07538 13.2947C6.04803 15.6527 8.42267 17.5093 11.133 18.823C12.1649 19.3121 13.5449 19.8923 15.0824 19.9917C15.1777 19.9959 15.2689 20 15.3642 20C16.3961 20 17.225 19.6436 17.9005 18.9101C17.9046 18.9059 17.9129 18.8976 17.9171 18.8893C18.1574 18.5993 18.431 18.3382 18.7169 18.0605C18.9117 17.874 19.1106 17.6792 19.3012 17.4803C20.184 16.5603 20.184 15.3916 19.293 14.5006L16.8023 12.0099C16.3796 11.5707 15.874 11.3386 15.3435 11.3386C14.8131 11.3386 14.3033 11.5707 13.8682 12.0058L12.3845 13.4894C12.2478 13.4107 12.1069 13.3402 11.9743 13.2739C11.8085 13.191 11.6552 13.1123 11.5184 13.0253C10.1674 12.1674 8.9407 11.0485 7.76788 9.61044C7.17526 8.86034 6.77742 8.23042 6.49975 7.58807C6.88931 7.23581 7.254 6.86697 7.60626 6.50642C7.73059 6.37795 7.85906 6.24948 7.98753 6.12101C8.4351 5.67344 8.67547 5.15541 8.67547 4.62909C8.67547 4.10278 8.43925 3.58475 7.98753 3.13717L6.75255 1.9022C6.6075 1.75715 6.47074 1.61625 6.32984 1.4712C6.05632 1.18939 5.77037 0.899296 5.48856 0.63821C5.06171 0.219644 4.56026 0 4.0298 0C3.50348 0 2.99789 0.219644 2.55446 0.642354L1.00452 2.19229C0.440905 2.75591 0.1218 3.4397 0.0554928 4.23125C-0.0232474 5.22172 0.159098 6.27435 0.631539 7.54662C1.35678 9.51513 2.45085 11.3427 4.07538 13.2947ZM1.06668 4.31828C1.11641 3.76709 1.32777 3.30709 1.72561 2.90924L3.26726 1.36759C3.50763 1.13552 3.77286 1.01533 4.0298 1.01533C4.2826 1.01533 4.53954 1.13552 4.77576 1.37588C5.05342 1.63282 5.31451 1.9022 5.59631 2.18815C5.73722 2.3332 5.88226 2.47824 6.02731 2.62743L7.26229 3.86241C7.51923 4.11935 7.65185 4.38044 7.65185 4.63738C7.65185 4.89432 7.51923 5.15541 7.26229 5.41235C7.13382 5.54082 7.00535 5.67344 6.87688 5.80191C6.49146 6.19146 6.13092 6.5603 5.73307 6.91256C5.72478 6.92085 5.72064 6.92499 5.71235 6.93328C5.36838 7.27725 5.42226 7.60464 5.50514 7.85329C5.50928 7.86573 5.51343 7.87402 5.51757 7.88645C5.83668 8.65313 6.28011 9.38251 6.97219 10.2528C8.21546 11.7862 9.52503 12.9755 10.9672 13.8914C11.1454 14.0075 11.3361 14.0986 11.5143 14.1898C11.68 14.2727 11.8334 14.3514 11.9701 14.4385C11.9867 14.4467 11.9991 14.455 12.0157 14.4633C12.1525 14.5338 12.2851 14.5669 12.4177 14.5669C12.7492 14.5669 12.9647 14.3556 13.0352 14.2851L14.5851 12.7352C14.8255 12.4948 15.0866 12.3663 15.3435 12.3663C15.6585 12.3663 15.9154 12.5611 16.077 12.7352L18.576 15.23C19.0733 15.7273 19.0692 16.2661 18.5636 16.7924C18.3895 16.9789 18.2072 17.1571 18.0124 17.3436C17.7223 17.6254 17.4198 17.9155 17.1463 18.2429C16.6697 18.7567 16.1019 18.9971 15.3684 18.9971C15.2979 18.9971 15.2233 18.993 15.1529 18.9888C13.7936 18.9018 12.5296 18.3713 11.5806 17.9196C9.00286 16.6722 6.74012 14.9026 4.86279 12.6564C3.31699 10.7957 2.27679 9.06341 1.58885 7.2068C1.162 6.06714 1.00037 5.15126 1.06668 4.31828Z"
                fill="#FF1A3B"
              />
            </svg>
            <a href="" class="header__phone-link">+7 (495) 111 99 88</a><span class="regular"> | <a href="" class="header__phone-link">+7 (495) 333 55 66</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__bottom">
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Главная</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Услуги</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Прайс</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Шиномонтаж</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Гарантии</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Полезная информация</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Контакты</a></li>
          </ul>
          <button class="nav__btn">Оставить заявку</button>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**SCSS**

```
.header {
  &__top,
  &__column,
  &__clock,
  &__geo,
  &__phone {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  &__bg {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }

  &__top {
    padding: 10px 0 8px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: rgba(14, 15, 40, 0.15);
  }

  &__clock,
  &__geo,
  &__phone {
    svg {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }

  &__bottom {
    padding: 7px 0 8px;
  }
}

.right {
  gap: 30px;
}
.red {
  color: $redColor;
}
.regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;

  &__list {
    display: flex;
    gap: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  &__item {
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  &__btn {
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: $whiteColor;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: $redColor;
    border: 1px solid #ff1a3b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    &:hover {
      color: $redColor;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Может вы лучше приложите css код и оформите код через "фрагмент кода" (ctrl+m)?

Comment: border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы забыли указать толщину и стиль бордера

```
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(14, 15, 40, 0.15);
```

Comment: Спасибо, копался с вёрсткой ночью и вообще в упор не видел проблемы)